# shell script counting the lines that meets in range values

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu, command-line

I have this :

```
 S=`cat sales.txt`;
    echo "$S" | cut -d: -f5 | grep -E '[0-9][0-9][0-9]' | wc -l
```

My Textfile : **name:id:number:type:value**

```
Tom:8:987654:A:67           //1
Dick:9:7651:B:83            //2
Harry:5:21215121:A:92       //3
Molly:2:1231872231:A:44     //4
Megan:123:322:B:145         //5
Russia:8:99231272:B:530     //6
Boleh:123:29321831:C:5000   //7
```

I am trying to count the number of lines whereby the 5th column value are in the range of 0-999 .

When I try to run , it gives me count of 3 where it should be 6 .

Answer (score 2):

Your two digit numbers don't match the regex `[0-9][0-9][0-9]`.

Also, storing a file in a variable and then printing it with `echo` is a *really* bad idea.  See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/135943), but even more to the point, you can just do `cat file` in place of the `echo` command.

Actually, you can do the whole thing with Awk, and then you don't even need `cat`.  Since you don't show any negative numbers, I'll just do a check for "less than one thousand."

```
awk -F: '$5 < 1000 {a++} END {print a}' sales.txt
```